# How to create a Fusebox project with multiple html pages?

Tags: bundle, fusebox

I'm new to bundlers and am currently learning about Fusebox. I really like it so far except that I can't figure out how to use it for a multi-page project. So far I've only been able to find a tutorial on [how to do this using webpack](https://medium.com/a-beginners-guide-for-webpack-2/multi-page-applications-4ae2ebfabc37), not for fusebox.

---

Input files in src folder:

- index.html
- index2.html
- index.ts

Desired output in dist folder:

- app.js
- vendor.js
- index.html
- index2.html

Actual output in dist folder:

- app.js
- vendor.js
- index.html

Here is my config in the fuse.js file:

```
Sparky.task("config", () => {
    fuse = FuseBox.init({
       homeDir: "src",
       output: "dist/$name.js",
       hash: isProduction,
       sourceMaps: !isProduction,
       plugins: [
           [SassPlugin(), CSSPlugin()],
           CSSPlugin(),
           WebIndexPlugin({ 
               title: "Welcome to FuseBox index",
               template: "src/index.html"
           },
           WebIndexPlugin({ 
               title: "Welcome to FuseBox index2",
               template: "src/index2.html"
           },
           isProduction && UglifyJSPlugin()
        ]
    });

    // vendor should come first
    vendor = fuse.bundle("vendor")
        .instructions("~ index.ts");

    // out main bundle
    app = fuse.bundle("app")
        .instructions(`!> [index.ts]`);

    if (!isProduction) {
        fuse.dev();
    }
});
```

Setting WebIndexPlugin twice within plugins doesn't work. What is the correct way to set up a multi-html page project with fusebox?

Comment: I don't think that you can do that. If you want this feature to be implemented, please submit an issue here https://github.com/fuse-box/fuse-box/issues

Answer (score 2):

The `WebIndexPlugin` can not be configured, to output more than one html file.

But if you don't use a hash for the generated bundles (e.g.: `output: "dist/$name.$hash.js"`), you don't need the `WebIndexPlugin` -- you can remove it completly from the `plugins` option. Because you already know the names of the generated bundles (`vendor.js` and `app.js`) you can just include the following lines

```
<script src="vendor.js"></script>
<script src="app.js"></script>
```

instead of the placeholder `$bundles`.

If you want, that both html files are copied from your `src` directory into your `dist` directory, you can add the following lines to your `fuse.js` script:

```
const fs = require('fs-extra');
fs.copySync('src/index.html', 'dist/index.html');
fs.copySync('src/index2.html', 'dist/index2.html');
```

Note: Don't forget to add `fs-extra:^5.0.0` to your `package.json`

Answer (score 1):

Might not been the case when the question was asked, but `WebIndexPlugin` now can be specified multiple times and also takes optional `bundles` parameter where list of bundles to be included in html can be specified (all bundles are included by default).

For example 2 html files (app1.html, app2.html) where each includes a common library (vendor.js), and different entry points (app1.js and app2.js)

- app1.html

  - vendor.js
  - app1.js
- app2.html

  - vendor.js
  - app2.js

Config would look like this:

```
const fuse = FuseBox.init({
    homeDir : "src",
    target : 'browser@es6',
    output : "dist/$name.js",
    plugins: [
        WebIndexPlugin({
            target: 'app1.html',
            bundles:['vendor', 'app1']
        }),
        WebIndexPlugin({
            target: 'app2.html',
            bundles:['vendor', 'app2']
        })
    ]
})
// vendor bundle, extracts dependencies from index1 and index2:
fuse.bundle("vendor").instructions("~[index1.ts,index2.ts]")

// app1 and app2, bundled separately without dependencies:
fuse.bundle("app1").instructions("!>index1.ts")
fuse.bundle("app2").instructions("!>index2.ts")
```

Comment: hi @Ski I am using 3.6 and it seems that the bundles are included only in the last WebIndexPlugin. Both html are generated this is ok but the first without bundles..